# What are the benefits of using a "choreography" pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

We're putting together a series of services using ASP.NET Web API. One proposal is to implement a "choreography" type design pattern where all clients connect to one endpoint and get routed based on the content of the GET and POST bodies. Another proposal is to just call each service directly.

What are the benefits of using a choreography-type design pattern?

Personally, I prefer one URL for all my services. It seems simpler but a single endpoint for simplicity isn't a valid argument.

**Update** - 
I'm open to using headers for the routing portion. We're at "conceptual level" design at the moment and I guess I didn't think about using headers before posting. The body will be JSON. I am proposing this be implemented using ASP.NET Web API 4. Based on the header, the choreographer will route to the appropriate endpoint for processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to route only based on the content of the GET and POST bodies then I would say that you would be reinventing SOAP which is now considered heavyweight and legacy.

If you include the HTTP headers in this decision then you will be more RESTFul which is a good thing. You might also checkout the [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) which might help you with this design.

Comment: Can you expand on  using Web API? Would each service be a different controller?